# Mongoose function findByIdAndUpdate is returning a null document

Tags: mongoose

I am running the Mongoose findByIdAndUpdate function (inside a Model Static function):

```
TemplateSchema.statics.archive = function(templateId, userId, callback) {

    let now = new Date();

    this.model('Template').findByIdAndUpdate(templateId, {
            discon: true,
            discon_date: now,
            discon_user_id: userId
        }, {new: true}, function(err, templateDoc){
            if(err){
                console.log("err:",err);
            }
            else{
                console.log("templateDoc:",templateDoc);
            }
        });
};
```

The console prints out `templateDoc: null`. Any idea why?

**Notes:**
In the Template schema, the `_id` field is specified as:

```
_id: {type: String}
```

When I do `console.log(typeof templateId)` , before running the `findByIdAndUpdate` function, it shows as `string`.

I am using Mongoose v4.7.6.

I have checked that the document does exist in the Mongo database.

I have checked the type of the `_id` field in Mongo and it is `String`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing that solved this was to do (though I have no idea why this is needing to be done if `templateId` is typeof `string`):

```
templateId = JSON.parse(templateId);
```